# How are those drums on Lorde Royals made?

Tags: sound, production, drum

Those Drums on Lordes Song Royals, especially the Big Verb style kick. What is it? Is it an Electronic One with reverb or accustic? Any help aprecciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok today i found it out when by accident. Its just a very soft acoustic kick drum that plays the underlying beat and offbeat. The Fingersnaps are heavy reverberated and compressed Fingersnaps and that Big Reverberated thing on the 1 Is just a very deep Flortom mixed with some far stereo Roommics. Great work Lorde, so simple so big!